# Error connecting with SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Hello I'm trying to connect to SQL server with Microsoft SQL server management studio. However when I try to connect I get the following error:

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-QELGJNT.

===================================

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

---

Error Number: 2
Severity: 20
State: 0
Usually you have to set up a server first before you can connect. How can I do this with SQL server management studio, if this is the reason I get this error.

I also checked under services but I couldn't click start on SQL server vss writer. That is the only sql file running I found.

I checked on YouTube and stackoverflow on a similar subject, however it didn't provide the solution for me. Could anyone help me?
This question can be helpful to others as well who have similar problems with SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SQL Server installed on your local computer? If yes.

Check your SQL Server Configuration Manager. If  SQL Server service is in Running state.

Answer (score 0):

It may possible your SQL Server service for that instance is stopped. There can be may reason one is due to service conflict with other. What you can do is

1. go to SQL Server Configuration Manager (type on start menu it will appear)
2. On left pan go to SQL Server Services
3. SQL Server() is running if not right click and start

If this will not resolve the issue then do check TCP/IP is enabled or not?
To enabled that

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. In the left pane, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and then
   click Protocols for MSSQLSERVER.
3. In the right pane, right-click TCP/IP, and then select Enable. 
       Double-click TCP/IP. The TCP/IP Properties dialog box is displayed.
4. On the IP Addresses tab, identify the block corresponding to the IP
       address that you want to enable.
5. In the Enabled field, select Yes.
6. In the TCP Port field, enter 1433.
7. Click OK.